# Printing a hex number as decimal in C

Tags: c, hex, printf, decimal

I am trying to print a hex number as decimal in C.

```
int main()
{
    unsigned long hex = 0xb5389e0c721a;
    printf("hex in dec: %lu", hex);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

From this, my output is 2651615770. However, when I used an online hex to dec converter and the Windows Calculator, the supposed output should be 199254774411802. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you on a 64 or 32 bit system? And what is your compiler?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: It is going to be on Windows (because of the `getch()`), so it doesn't actually matter whether it is 32-bit or 64-bit Windows; the size of `unsigned long` is 4 on both.

Answer (score 2):

I think Your `2651615770` output is due to overflowing. It's because a 32-bit `unsigned long hex` cannot hold a number this big(`0xb5389e0c721a`), so it needs bigger data type.

Try the following change-

```
int main()
{
    unsigned long long hex = 0xb5389e0c721a; // declare hex as unsigned long long
    printf("hex in dec: %llu", hex);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong?

You are using the `unsigned long` type, which is only guaranteed to be 32-bit wide and may not be able to contain the value `0xb5389e0c721a`. Use `unsigned long long` instead, which is guaranteed to be at least 64-bit wide, and print with `%llu`.

The maximum value that `unsigned long` can contain is fixed for a given compilation platform. It is in the macro `ULONG_MAX` from the system header `limits.h`. You can also print its value for your compiler without having to include `limits.h` with the statement `printf("%lu", (unsigned long)-1);`.

Comment: In this case the compiler *should* give a warning (not mandatory, but a good QoI issue)

Answer (score 0):

The value `0xb5389e0c721a` exceeds the limit of an `unsigned long`.  Use 'unsigned long long' type instead, and print the value with a format string of `"%llx"`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
   {
   unsigned long long hex = 0xb5389e0c721a;

   printf("hex in dec: %llx\n", hex);
   return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Printing with `%llx` is not going to achieve the initial objective of converting to decimal.